# admin site doesn't show object fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, gis, django-contrib

I have a model with a [`PointField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.PointField) from **django.contrib.gis.db.models** . This somehow doesn't let the admin site show the objects with a nice table of fields and values. Instead it displays one field named after the model name. The values are just a bunch of ' object'. With  the name of the model. If I click the object I can edit it fine. It would be nice however to be able to filter and see the field values at the admin/ page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`PointField` does **not**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py#L273) have a [`__unicode__` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode), for the proper name to show up, you can register a new admin model object.

Now, in [the admin's `list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display),

```
class PointFieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'field_x', 'field_y', ...)

admin.register(PointField, PointFieldAdmin)
```

More on admin [models registering here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

Comment: so this means there is no built-in support in Django to use this field in an admin site? Is there a better way than changing the python files of Django itself?

Comment: Is the models from a 3rd party app?

Comment: I changed the first line of my post: the model is PointField. It's from django.contrib.gis.db.models

Comment: Well, Check the edit. Changing the model name for 3rd party types is not a useful way to express what you are looking to achieve :P